# Tornado XSRF token without templating

Tags: post, backbone.js, cookies, tornado, csrf

I am currently implementing a project containing Backbone Marionette over Tornado and am running into an issue with the XSRF token. Since the XSRF is not delivered through a template (by means of xsrf_form_html() ), when a user logs in the app makes a GET request to the login url "//login" and retrieves the xsrf token by means of:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
"""
"""

def get(self):
    token = self.xsrf_token
    self.respond(dict(_xsrf=token))
```

self.respond looks like:

```
def respond(self, response=None):
    """
    :param data:
    :return:
    """

    if response is not None:
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.write(json.dumps(response))
    else:
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.write("")
```

However, whenever a POST (with a field value of `"_xsrf" : token` ) is made to the server, I get the iconic " XSRF cookie does not match POST argument". It looks as if the xsrf token on the server is being re-generated at every request since the xsrf cookie does not exist (so far my attempts to ensure that the cookie exists has failed...not entirely sure how to persist that). Perhaps I'm missing (or misunderstanding) something critical here, but I was hoping someone else out there had encountered a paradigm like this and has a solution or suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xsrf token has to be sent in two different ways and they have to match.  Once in the cookie, and once either in a header or in a form-encoded POST body (the body cannot be json and must have a form-encoded or multipart content-type).  Headers are generally preferred as long as your clients can send them; you need to send both `Cookie: _xsrf=foo` and `X-Xsrf-Token: foo`.

Since Tornado 3.2.2, xsrf tokens include a random component to counter the BREACH attack, so two tokens can match without being identical.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks - I realized this about 30 minutes after posting this and forgot to respond to my own question. I suppose I was hoping that Tornado also had a persistent store for this (which, in retrospect, I'm not really sure why I was hoping that...). Thanks for your response. What would your opinion be about wrapping an encryption around the cookie xsrf and a decoder in the back to prevent possible leakage of the token?

Comment: I'm not sure how encryption would help here since the point of the xsrf token is that legitimate clients can see it and pass it back to you.  You'll have to be more clear about your threat model and how you intend to manage keys (I don't think a global symmetric key makes sense, although a per-user and/or asymmetric key might).  I think a stateful session scheme is more likely to yield security improvements than adding encryption to the randomized token.

Comment: I was giving it more thought, and while the overall goal would be to prevent a malicious agent from obtaining the token and using it, that wouldn't particularly mitigate it, so I take that thought back. Persisting it and overriding the get_xsrf_token to pull from the backend rather than sending it in the response header would be better. Thanks again for your help! I'd upvote if I had more than 15 rep (as soon as I do, I'll remember to come back and do so)